# Regex match line breaks inside an html div

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text structured like this:

```
1) CF582 Sortis (10): x 1 tabl.;
2) CF583 Sortis (20 mg): 2 x 1 tabl.;
3) CF734 Sortis (40 mg): 3 x 1 tabl.;
```

I need a regex that matches all digits at the beginning of each line (but not somewhere after the beginning as ***10)*** on the first line) plus the closing bracket.

Which is not a big deal for a plain text like this. The problem is that the text comes preformatted as the div innerHTML of the snippet I am attaching, and neither the ^, nor the \n characters match the new lines.

```js
var myTherapyDiv = document.getElementById("mytherapy");

myTherapyDiv.innerHTML = myTherapyDiv.innerHTML.replace(/;(\s*\d*\))/g, ";<br>\n$1")

// therapy numbered list outline
myTherapyDiv.innerHTML = myTherapyDiv.innerHTML.replace(/(\b\d+\))/g, "<span style='color: red'>$1</span>");
```

```html
<div class="inputcontents" id="mytherapy"> 1) CF582 Sortis (10): x 1 tabl.; 2) CF583 Sortis (20 mg): 2 x 1 tabl.; 3) CF734 Sortis (40 mg): 3 x 1 tabl.;</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current regexes ? What do they do, that shouldnt be doing ? Or what do they not do, that they should be doing ?

Comment: Once you match them, what will you do with it?

Comment: @ Isaac: If you run the code snippet, you'll see that not only the leading digits are matched, but also those somewhere in between as I have pointed out - the "10)" string must not match.

Comment: @ Matus Dubrava: please run the snippet. Stated differently, the numbers (plus the bracket) showing the order in the numbered list should be outlined only, not any other numbers in between.

Comment: If the `;` is what separates the lines, why not just use the first regex to capture all, with a preceding `;` or `^` ? This avoids having to use one regex to separate by lines and the another one to get the numbers

Comment: @ Isaac: I would prefer a solution that modifies the second regex, if possible. The data comes in from a database that I cannot control, that modifies the text by itself, sometimes unpredictably (at least to me).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to highlight the first numbers of each line then you can do it like this.

Get the `textContent` of the desired element, split it at `;` and process each line separately in a loop.

```js
var myTherapyDiv = document.getElementById("mytherapy");
const lines = myTherapyDiv.textContent.split(';').filter(v => v !== '');
myTherapyDiv.innerHTML = '';

lines.forEach(line => {
  line = line.replace(/(\s*\d*\))/, "<span style='color: red'>$1</span>");
  myTherapyDiv.innerHTML += line + ";<br />";
});
```

```html
<div class="inputcontents" id="mytherapy"> 1) CF582 Sortis (10): x 1 tabl.; 2) CF583 Sortis (20 mg): 2 x 1 tabl.; 3) CF734 Sortis (40 mg): 3 x 1 tabl.;</div>
```

If you want to solve it only by using regex then you can try this (although not very elegant).

```js
var myTherapyDiv = document.getElementById("mytherapy");

myTherapyDiv.innerHTML = myTherapyDiv.innerHTML.replace(/;(\s*\d*\))/g, ";<br>\n$1")
myTherapyDiv.innerHTML = myTherapyDiv.innerHTML.replace(/^\s*(\d+\))/, "<span style='color: red'>$1</span>");
myTherapyDiv.innerHTML = myTherapyDiv.innerHTML.replace(/<br>(\s*\d+\))/g, "<br><span style='color: red'>$1</span>");
```

```html
<div class="inputcontents" id="mytherapy"> 1) CF582 Sortis (10): x 1 tabl.; 2) CF583 Sortis (20 mg): 2 x 1 tabl.; 3) CF734 Sortis (40 mg): 3 x 1 tabl.;</div>
```

Which can be simplified by merging the first `replace` with the third one like this.

```js
var myTherapyDiv = document.getElementById("mytherapy");

myTherapyDiv.innerHTML = myTherapyDiv.innerHTML.replace(/;(\s*\d*\))/g, ";<br><span style='color: red'>$1</span>");
myTherapyDiv.innerHTML = myTherapyDiv.innerHTML.replace(/^\s*(\d+\))/, "<span style='color: red'>$1</span>");
```

```html
<div class="inputcontents" id="mytherapy"> 1) CF582 Sortis (10): x 1 tabl.; 2) CF583 Sortis (20 mg): 2 x 1 tabl.; 3) CF734 Sortis (40 mg): 3 x 1 tabl.;</div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why my second regex won't work, even if I substitute the ^ or \n for the \b?  The code above is for demonstration purposes and the last regex is applied after a chain of many other, not included here for simplicity. So the only practical solution to me is to modify the second regex provided in my snippet.

Comment: @SamoZaparola See the updated regex solution if it helps.

Comment: @SamoZaparola `^` will work, but it matches the start of the string so it will match only the first number. `\n` can't work as there are no new lines (`\n`) in that string, `<br> !== \n`. So you need to check separately for `^` as well as `<br>`. As in the second solution above.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is my solution based on your answer:
myTherapyDiv.innerHTML = myTherapyDiv.innerHTML.replace(/(^|<br>)\s*(\d+\))/g, "$1<span class='inputorderedlist'>$2</span>");